# How do I revert from the nvidia-381 driver to xserver-xorg-video-nouveau?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lightdm

I selected the recommended nvidia-381 driver from the Additional Drivers settings page in Ubuntu 16.10. After restarting, the system is stuck at the splash screen.

I tried starting in recovery mode to access the root shell. From there, I tried uninstalling the Nvidia driver, stopping LightDM, and installing the default one. These are the commands I used:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge nvidia-*
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

I had problems with every step. First, after removing the Nvidia driver, it still shows in the driver list. Second, LightDM will not stop because it says:

> Unable to connect to upstart: connection refused

Third, when I install the default driver, it says the newest version is already installed. But when I restart, nothing happens.

I repeated these steps 5 times.

Is there any way I could connect to the internet through my root shell?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the most efficient method but this is what I did.

1) Use ubuntu live usb  to download the  latest driver from NVIDIA and save the file in the disk on your computer.

2)Reboot into recovery to root terminal.

3)sudo apt-get remove nvidia*

4)cd to the place where you have saved the driver

5)chmod 777 NVIDIA-Linux-{version}.run

6)$ sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-{version}.run

This is what worked for me.